# Splunk group by request url count

Tags: java, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I have a below event listed in Splunk. It logs the distinct API call made to services. Like in below example my-bag , my-basket , my-cart as distinct services and URL pattern of call is always **/api/{service-name}/{v1 or v2 }/{ method name}? token = {dynamic token}**.
How to group by its service and get the respective count.

Group By output

```
Service Count
-----------
my-bag    2
my-basket 2
my-cart   1
```

Logs

```
[host=abc.com request="GET /api/my-bag/v1/add?token=8989khk768yb887" status="200" ]
[host=abc.com request="GET /api/my-basket/v1/max?token=798797hjkhjkjgh8" status="200" ]
[host=abc.com request="GET /api/my-cart/v1/add?token=78765hghjgjh" status="200" ]
[host=abc.com request="GET /api/my-bag/v1/add?token=799865mnbjhgj6" status="200" ]
[host=abc.com request="GET /api/my-basket/v1/count?token=787jkhkjhk" status="200" ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
your original search
| rex "(GET|POST|DELETE|PATCH) /api/(?<service>[\w\-]+)/"
| stats count by service
```

Comment: It could be GET or POST or DELETE or PATCH any protocol in start of the request . How I can accommodate that

Comment: Updated. Just use `|` as `or`.

Comment: Thanks ! I have a continuation question open at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73993208/splunk-group-by-stats-with-where-condition

Comment: Replied there as well